# Adding reward ads in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am adding reward ads to my flutter app but I am getting this error. I also want to ad score once rewarded ads get viewed.

```
I/Choreographer(30860): Skipped 21 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/Ads     (30860): Update ad debug logging enablement as false
W/Ads     (30860): Not retrying to fetch app settings
W/ConnectionStatusConfig(30860): Dynamic lookup for intent failed for action: com.google.android.gms.ads.service.START
I/DynamiteModule(30860): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite:224400003
I/DynamiteModule(30860): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.ads.dynamite, version >= 224400003
I/Ads     (30860): This request is sent from a test device.
W/Ads     (30860): Not retrying to fetch app settings
I/Ads     (30860): Ad failed to load : 3
```

**my code**

class purchase extends StatefulWidget {
const purchase({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

```
 @override
 State<purchase> createState() => _purchaseState();
```

}

class _purchaseState extends State {

```
 RewardedAd? _rewardedAd;
 int _rewardedScore = 0;

 void  _createRewardedAd() {
   RewardedAd.load(
       adUnitId: AdMobService.rewardedAdUnitId!,
       request: AdRequest(),
       rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
           onAdLoaded: (ad) => setState(() => _rewardedAd = ad),
           onAdFailedToLoad: (error) => setState(() => _rewardedAd =
```

null)));
}

```
 void _showRewardedAd(){
   print(' dnull');

   if(_rewardedAd != null){
     print('not null');
     _rewardedAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = 
FullScreenContentCallback(
         onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad){
           ad.dispose();
           _createRewardedAd();
         },
         onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad,error){
           ad.dispose();
           _createRewardedAd();
         }
     );
     _rewardedAd!.show(onUserEarnedReward: (ad, reward) 
  =>setState(()=> _rewardedScore++));
     _rewardedAd = null;
   }
 }

  @override
 void initState() {
   // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
_createRewardedAd();
```

}

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     body: Container(
       child: Column(
         children: [
           Text('Rewarded score is : $_rewardedScore',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
           ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
             _showRewardedAd();
           }, child: Text('earns coins')),
         ],
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
```

}